# Textbox control inside of a textbox control ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nested, textbox

I was curious if its possible to put a textbox inside of a textbox.

[image: Nested Textboxes]

and if so, how? and how would I call the data from the inner most textbox and posted it to a confirmation page (if its different than normal since its nested)?

I am using ASP.Net C#

Comment: That looks like 2 textboxes side by side to me. If that's a screenshot from a website, just look at the page's HTML and check the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think those are two textboxes seeming as one. You can achieve that by using **2 textboxes and css**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

Script:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

Here is the codepen demo: https://codepen.io/rohan-rao-the-bashful/pen/wvGEVEe

HTML:

```
<div class="container p-3">
  <label>Additional Phone number
    <div class="d-flex">
      <input type="number" />
      <input type="number" placeholder="ext" style="width:80px; padding:10px" />
    </div>
</div>
```